# Добавить jQuery noConflict

Tags: jquery

К странице в тег `head` добавляется такой код

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Для корректного отображения в ие, однако добавление respond.min.js ломает работу других скриптов на странице. Если добавить к этим скриптам jQuery noConflict, это может помочь решить проблему совместимости с другими скриптами? как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Конфликт, скорее всего из-за использования “***$***” в качестве объявления переменной/функций в **jQuery**. Многие библиотеки **JS**, тоже используют этот символ для своих нужд. ***.noConflict()*** – отключает/заменяет потребность в такого рода объявлениях.
Вот, это должно помочь:
http://w3pro.ru/book/spravochnik-po-jquery-api/jquerynoconflict

Comment: я не могу разобраться, как мне надо сделать. если я подключаю в хэд страницы тот код, что у меня приведен в вопросе, то у меня показывает, что другой скрипт, который мне тоже нужен, не находит http://i.imgur.com/fx01445.png, если убираю из хеда код, то этот скрипт подключается и работает.

Comment: Сверху вашего JS кода (под библиотеками), объявите:

    jQuery.noConflict();

И замените все объявления, от jQuery на    jQuery("переменная").метод

Или используйте объявления jQuery внутри redy():

    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       // Код jQuery с использованием $
    });

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в моем случае оказалось достаточным подключить скрипты из вопроса **после** всех скриптов проекта)

Comment: @HA3IK

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});

полностью эквивалентно  

    jQuery(function($) {});

Comment: @Heidel, Логично. Как он может конфликтовать с тем, что уже отработало )  

@eicto, Спс, кинул в свою копилку знаний )